# Discord.js Reddit Command works in VS Code, but not in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, reddit

I wrote a code that sends memes. It works great in VS Code, but when i run it in Heroku, it doesn't do anything. Could it be something with Heroku against Reddit? Please help me!

```
var randomsub = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes.json?sort=top&t=week', 'https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json?sort=top&t=week']
    const randomsubs = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomsub.length)
    message.channel.startTyping()
    try {
        const { body } = await snekfetch
            .get(randomsub[randomsubs])
            .query({ limit: 800 });
        const allowed = message.channel.nsfw ? body.data.children : body.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.over_18);
        if (!allowed.length) return message.channel.send('**Looks like I'm all out of memes, try again later!**').then(msg => {msg.delete(5000)});
        const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)
        message.channel.send(`**${allowed[randomnumber].data.title}**`)
        message.channel.send(allowed[randomnumber].data.url)
        message.channel.send(`*${" : " + allowed[randomnumber].data.ups + " | " + " : " + allowed[randomnumber].data.num_comments}*`)
        message.channel.stopTyping()
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Snekfetch is deprecated, use node-fetch instead